# If AD account exists, append a counter to the username started at 2

Tags: powershell

The following script is adding accounts to the Active Directory. In case the username already exists, I want to append a number to the username and try again.

i.e. if `cs15csa` already exists, it should try again with `cs1csa2`. If `cs1csa2` exists, it should then try with `cs1csa3` and so on and so forth.

How do I do that?

```
# Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv export.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
       $Username    = $User.username
       $Password    = $User.password
       $Firstname   = $User.firstname
       $Lastname    = $User.lastname
       $OU          = $User.ou

       # Check if the user account already exists in AD
       if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
       {
              # If user does exist, output a warning message
              Write-Warning "A user account $Username ($Firstname $Lastname) already exists in the Active Directory."
       }
       else
       {
              # If a user does not exist then create a new user account
              # Account will be created in the OU listed in the $OU variable in the CSV file; don't forget to change the domain name in the"-UserPrincipalName" variable
              New-ADUser `
              -SamAccountName $Username `
              -UserPrincipalName "$Username@iit.uni-ruse.bg" `
              -Email "$Username@iit.uni-ruse.bg" `
              -ProfilePath '\\leo\%USERNAME%\Profile' `
              -Name "$Username" `
              -GivenName $Firstname `
              -Surname $Lastname `
              -Enabled $True `
              -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
              -Path $OU `
              -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a loop to test the SamAccountName and inside keep adding a counter number to it until you have found a unique name.

To avoid having to use those nasty backticks on the New-ADUser cmdlet, I would advise to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

Also, `'\\leo\%USERNAME%\Profile'` should be `"\\leo\$Username\Profile"`

Try

```
# Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-Csv export.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $Username    = $User.username

    # Check if the user account already exists in AD and keep adding 
    # a counter value to the SamAccountName until unique
    $count = 2
    while (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'") {
        $Username = '{0}{1}' -f $User.username, $count++
    }
    # create the new user using a Splatting Hashtable
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName    = $Username
        UserPrincipalName = "$Username@iit.uni-ruse.bg"
        EmailAddress      = "$Username@iit.uni-ruse.bg"
        ProfilePath       = "\\leo\$Username\Profile"
        Name              = $Username
        GivenName         = $User.firstname
        Surname           = $User.lastname
        Enabled           = $true
        DisplayName       = '{0} {1}' -f $User.firstname, $User.lastname
        Path              = $User.ou
        AccountPassword   = $User.password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    }
    # create the user
    New-ADUser @userParams
}
```

---

An alternative to the while loop above (might be faster, depending on how many similar SamAccountNames there may be in your environment) would be to do this:

```
# Check if the user account already exists in AD and keep adding 
# a counter value to the SamAccountName until unique
# first get an array of similar SamAccountNames already present
$similarNames = @((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$Username*'").SamAccountName)
$count = 2
while ($similarNames -contains $Username) {
    $Username = '{0}{1}' -f $User.username, $count++
}
```